# Can I relate a node with a taxonomy term via its description and not its name?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I import xml files into Drupal. These files use numbers for location which I want later to be interpreted into names (like Spain, Greece etc). So I would like the taxonomy terms to have the name of the countries but then how could I relate the node to the taxonomy term? I was thinking to use the description or another taxonomy field to relate it with the node instead of the name. Is that possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use drupal 7 you add a term reference field to the content type, and choose which taxonomy terms are related to the node on the add/edit page for the node. There refs are done by term id (tid) not by name/description